# Crate with diesel and mysql dependencies no longer compiles against mariadb after upgrading NixOS to 20.03

Tags: rust, nixos, rust-diesel

My crate, which depends on [diesel](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/index.html) with the `mysql` feature enabled, no longer compiles after upgrading my system from [NixOS](https://nixos.org) 19.09 to 20.03. It seems the only significant change is an update of the `mariadb-server` package from 10.2.17 to 10.3.18. There is no change to the Rust toolchain etc. (it's statically pinned in `nix-shell` to [nightly](https://github.com/mozilla/nixpkgs-mozilla) 2020-04-20).

The [very long compiler message](https://pastebin.com/YJVfi15y) starts with:

```
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This build script that [tells](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-link-lib) Cargo to link the crate using the compiler's flag `-lmariadb solved the issue:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=mariadb");
}
```

**Update 2020-05-01**

Actually the issue could be solved in [mysqlclient-sys](https://github.com/sgrif/mysqlclient-sys/issues/25) crate.